# regular expression to find spaces is failing

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to find groups of spaces and replace them with another character like $

```
 $teststring="00005e-000003 D21    3       0004ea-287342 D21    3       000883-d94982 D21    3       000f20-4c5241 D21    3       002561-e32140 D21    3       003018-a1a24f D21    3       00e039-0fe0fe D21    3       08000f-1eb958 D21    3       08000f-1ec4de D21    3       082e5f-498900 D21    3";
 $pattern='/([0-9A-F]{6})-([0-9A-F]{6}) ([0-9A-F]+)\s{1,}([0-9]{1,})/i'; 

 if (preg_match_all($pattern,$teststring,$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {   
        $data = $matches[0];
 }
```

this is working in that based on my pattern, if i do a print_r on $data, it looks like:

```
 Array ( 
          [0] => 00005e-000003 D21 3 
          [1] => 0004ea-287342 D21 3 
          [2] => 000883-d94982 D21 3 

       }
```

what I'd like to do is replace all spaces with $
so the output looks like this:

```
 Array ( 
          [0] => 00005e-000003$D21$3 
          [1] => 0004ea-287342$D21$3 
          [2] => 000883-d94982$D21$3 
  }
```

Can you tell me how i can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is replace all groups of spaces with one dollar sign, you can do something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/','$', $subject);
```

Also as an aside:

- You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to match one digit
- You can use `+` to match one or more character instead of `{1,}`
- Instead of using `//i` to do a case-insensitive search, I think making your hex character class `[0-9a-fA-F]` would be a little more efficient... though I didn't do the leg work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use preg_replace instead

Comment: can you give me an example of how i would do that? I did play around with a bit but i wasn't able to get it going.

Comment: If I got it correctly, you have all data as a plain text in $teststring. Then extract the samples with your original pattern into $data , so you get your $data array populated. After this apply to $data the following: $data = preg_replace('/\\s+/','\\$',$data);

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$ret = preg_replace('/([\da-f]{6}-[\da-f]{6}) ([\da-f]+)\s+(\d+)/i', '\1$\2$\3', $teststring);
```